# Security Issues in Rails raised by Brakeman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, brakeman

In my project,while using [Brakeman gem](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman), following security issues is raised:

1) In the following statement, `Unescaped model attribute` error is raised

```
CashTransaction.find(session[:transaction_id]).customer.address_1
```

I know Rails uses a cookie based session store. However, Rails 4 it's  relatively safe to use cookies as you would need the `Rails secret token` in order to compromise it.

So, is this a false positive? If not how can I remove this vulnerability?

2) Secondly, I have a scenario where I need to check whether a record with a typical attribute exists or not. For that I have following code

```
  def check_email
    render json: ( is_available('email', params[:user][:email]) )
  end

  def is_email_available
    is_email_taken = is_available('email', params[:user][:email])
    render json: !is_email_taken
  end

  def is_username_available
    is_username_taken = is_available('username', params[:user][:username])
    render json: !is_username_taken
  end

  def is_available(type, value)
    User.where("#{type}=?", value).exists?
  end
```

And Brakeman raises the following warning

```
Possible SQL injection. User.where("#{(local type)}=?", (local value))
```

How can I remove this vulnerability and at the same time make my code DRY?

Comment: For the last one, is "value" an input from the user?

Comment: yes, it can be an email or a username

Comment: To me the second looks fine - it would be a problem if you had User.where("#{type}= #{value}).exists? -  not sure why brakeman would flag that.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet#SQL_Injection is the gem up to date?

Comment: Just out of curiosity try this: User.where( type: value).exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part:

If `type` is not an user input, you can do

```
User.where(type.to_sym => value)
```

If it's a user-input you should be doing.

```
User.where("%s =  %s" % [type, "'#{value}'"])
```